# Getting list of selected checkboxes in table

Tags: grails, checkbox

This is what I have in table:

```
<td><g:checkBox name="book_${bookInstance.id}"/> </td>
```

And this is how I try to get selected instances:

```
params.each{
            if(it.key.startsWith("book_"))
                books << (it.key - "book_") as Integer
        }
```

I'm getting an empty list. How to fix this? I'm open to suggestions if u have a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

Try creating the list of checkboxes with all the same input name, but different values.

```
<g:each in="${books}" var="bookInstance">
    <g:checkBox name="books" value="${bookInstance.id}"/>
</g:each>
```

Then in your controller you can get the list of selected book IDs via:

```
params.list('books')
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. I did exactly the same thing and I get an empty list. And even if it worked I would expect it to return all instances not just the selected ones. Some help/clarification would be great.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem(or at list the part of it) is I'm submitting the form with <g:jasperReport> wich passess only the parameters defined in the g:jasperReport tag.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is definitely late since the question was asked a while back. Anyway I solved a similar problem, please try this.

```
<td><g:checkBox name="registerBook" value="${bookInstance.id}" checked="false"/> </td>
```

Controller code to get the list of selected books:

```
def checkedBooks = params.list('registerBook')
//get list of books. this will return only the selected books
def selectedBooks = Book.getAll(checkedBooks)

for(result in selectedBooks){
//now manipulate the result as you wish ...
}
```